# How can i transmit received data into some other controller in raspberry-pi3 using uart?

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi, pyserial

From lpc2148 I'm using a single switch button to transmit hex data(ex: `char ch[6]={0x12, 0x13,0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17}`) to raspi receiver uart(ttyS0),
and then I want to transmit the received data into some other controller. If I press the switch button, the rpi receives the data fine, but when I press and hold the button data should transmit and be received continuously in raspi but I'm unable to transmit the received data into another controller when using python. In C, it's working fine, but the same program I converted to python is not working. Please do help me, I'm stuck here. I'm a beginner to python.

NOTE: I'm working on raspi-3

c-code

```
    while(1)
    {
           serial_port = serialOpen ("/dev/ttyS0", 9600) 

        if(serialDataAvail (serial_port) )

        { 
                for(i=0;i<6;i++)
                   {
            data[i] = serialGetchar (serial_port);
                   }
        }

    serialclose(serial_port)

    serial_port2=serialOpen("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600)

      for(j=0;j<6;j++)

    serialputchar(serial_port2,data[j])

    serialclose(serial_port2)
    }
```

The above C code is working fine with the help of this page 
http://wiringpi.com/reference/serial-library/
When I try to convert the program into python it's not working:

```py
import serial
from time import sleep
while True:
       ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyS0", 9600)
       received_data = ser.read()                 #read serial port
       while ser.inWaiting()<1 :
           data_left = ser.inWaiting()             #check for remaining byte
           received_data += ser.read(data_left)
       ser.close   #closed port1  once data received 
       ser2= serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600)
       #ser2.write(received_data)
       for i in received_data
          ser2.write(i) 
       ser2.close()
```

The data is receiving perfectly and it's not coming out from the inner while loop (`while ser.inWaiting()<1 :`)

How can I check if the data is available on the port, like in C-code `serialDataAvail()`.

I traced `ser.inWaiting()` returning always zero.

I Googled this, but no explanations are available for `pyserial` library's equivalent library function to `serialDataAvail()` for python

Comment: `ser.close` should be `ser.close()`, by the way

Comment: Are you always going to be sending exactly 6 bytes at a time? If so, you can just get rid of the entire inner `while` loop and just change `received_data = ser.read()` to `received_data = ser.read(6)`

Comment: tq u so much its working fine. @thisisbenmanley do u have any idea about how can i control rpi GPIO through uart                                                                        for ex: i'm using 2 switches on Raspi  to control LED's. i want to control the Raspi GPIO through uart??

Comment: You don't control GPIO "through UART," you have to look up a separate library to use in order to control the GPIO pins. Look at [this example](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/27968772-turning-on-an-led-with-your-raspberry-pis-gpio-pins) of using GPIO to control LEDs

Comment: okay tq for ua response